# Custom Column rearrange using references from another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I've been struggling to make this work as intended. As you can see, I have A38 cell as the range that will define how columns rearrange. This number comes from another sheet, and whenever I change it (from the sheet it comes from), the columns from the sheet that has this code won't rearrange automatically, I have to go to the cell A38, select it and press enter to make it work, do you guys know how I can make this automatically?

```
.
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.Volatile
ActiveSheet.Activate
If Not Application.Intersect(Range("A38"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        Select Case Target.Value
        Case Is = "2": Columns("K:T").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                            Columns("I:J").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Case Is = "3": Columns("L:T").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                           Columns("I:K").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Case Is = "4": Columns("M:T").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                            Columns("I:L").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Case Is = "5": Columns("N:T").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                            Columns("I:M").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Case Is = "6": Columns("O:T").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                            Columns("I:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Case Is = "7": Columns("P:T").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                            Columns("I:O").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Case Is = "8": Columns("Q:T").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                            Columns("I:P").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Case Is = "9": Columns("r:t").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                            Columns("I:Q").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Case Is = "10": Columns("s:t").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                            Columns("I:R").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Case Is = "11": Columns("T:T").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                            Columns("I:S").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Case Is = "12": Columns("S:T").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                            Columns("I:T").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        End Select
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Use `Worksheet_Calculate` instead of `Worksheet_Change`.... and drop the `Application.Volatile`. Note that `Worksheet_Calculate` has no parameters.

Comment: it says "procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name", should I change something else? Thank you.

Comment: `Worksheet_Calculate` has no parameters, i.e. no `Target`. Drop the `If Not Application.Intersect(Range("A38"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then`... and change `Select Case Target.Value` to `Select Case Me.Range("A38").Value`.

Comment: should i also change `Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate(ByVal Target As Range)`, I mean, what should i use instead of "target"? it gives me an error there, it says **procedure declaration does not match description of event**

Comment: `Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()` - see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.calculate(even)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Worksheet_Calculate` instead of `Worksheet_Change`:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    With Me
        Select Case .Range("A38").Value
            Case "2"
                .Columns("K:T").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                .Columns("I:J").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
            Case "3"
                .Columns("L:T").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                .Columns("I:K").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
            ' and so on
       End Select
    End With
End Sub
```